# Showing that the projections of a product are jointly monic

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, universal-property

Suppose that we have a category $\mathcal{C}$ which "has binary products" (full definition provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)). We want to show that given $A, B, C \in \mathcal{C}$ and morphisms $f, g : A \to B \times C$, $$f = g \iff p_1 \circ f = p_1 \circ g \text{ and } p_2 \circ f = p_2 \circ g$$

For the forward direction, I think I have a working proof:

Suppose that $f = g$. Then $\forall x$ $f(x) = g(x)$. Consider arbitrary $x \in A$ and suppose that $f(x) = g(x) = y$. Then $p_1(f(x)) = p_1(y) = p_1(y) = p_1(g(x))$ and similarly, $p_2(f(x)) = p_2(y) = p_2(y) = p_2(g(x))$. Since our choice of $x$ was arbitrary, $p_1 \circ f = p_1 \circ g$ and $p_2 \circ f = p_2 \circ g$.

One concern with the forward direction that I have is that can we really say $p_1 (f(x)) = p_1(y) = p_1(g(x)) \implies p_1(f(x)) = p_1(g(x))$ without knowing injectivity/surjectivity of $f$ and $g$? I think the answer to this question is yes.

For the reverse direction I'm completely stuck. I can't get past the fact that $f : A \to B$ and $p_1 : B \times C \to B$. The inputs and outputs to $p_1$ and $f$ don't match so we can't really have something like $p_1 \circ f$, right? Similar things happen with $g$ as well as $p_2$.

Edit: I was thinking of $f : A \to B$ and $g : A \to C$ but it should be $f, g : A \to B \times C$ as edited above. Still confused about the reverse direction.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Since $f$ is from $A$ to $B$, and $g$ is from $A$ to $C$, it's impossible for $f=g$. Did you make a typo?

Comment: That is what the question states. Perhaps it would also imply that $B = C$?

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. Like you said, you can't compose $p_1$ and $f$. However, if you take $f$ and $g$ to go from $A$ to $B \times C$, then you can use the uniqueness in the universal property for products.

Comment: Ohhh. Whoopsies, I thought that $f, g : A \to B \times C$ is essentially the same as $f : A \to B$ and $g : A \to C$. My mistake. I've editted. Should make more sense now.
Edit: Makes a lot more sense now. At least the $p_1 \circ f$ composition stuff.

Comment: In a general category, morphisms are not maps, hence you cannot argue with "$f(x)$" and the like. Nevertheless $f=g\implies p\circ f=p\circ g$ is an immediate logical consequence of the properties of identiy

Comment: What do you mean by properties of identity? The statement $f = g \implies p \circ f = p \circ g$ seems to be true for all morphisms $p$, but is there a formal justification for that?

Comment: @real_father The formal justification composition $\circ$ is a function on sets of morphisms.

Comment: isn't that just the uniqueness of the map in the universal property? ($\Leftarrow$ is clear just by calculation, $\Rightarrow$ lets assume the righthandside, then we have a unique map $\varphi: A \to B\times C$ such that $p_1 \circ \varphi = p_1 \circ f = p_1 \circ g$ and $p_2 \circ \varphi = p_2 \circ f = p_2 \circ g$, but  $f$ and $g$ also fulfil this property, in particular by the uniquness we get $f=g=\varphi$)

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I'll give it a go since no one has put a dedicated answer.

There are two types of axioms. Axioms of the language you are using (logical axioms), and axioms of the theory of interest.

$$ h = k \implies p_a \circ h = p_a \circ k  \ \land \ p_b \circ h = p_b \circ k$$

is the result of the logical axioms of first-order logic (See *Propositional and Predicate Calculus*, Goldrei, Section 5.2, *Axioms for equality*)

To prove the other direction requires the axioms/theorems of category theory: (I apologize for posting a pdf. I already had an answer typed using tikzcd, which apparently isn't compatible with this site, so I can't upload the $\LaTeX$ code)

[image]